# I have a routing problem on my Angular project

Tags: angular

I have a problem with the routing on my project.
My router look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':city',
    component: AppComponent,
  },
];
```

And on my component page I try to get the parameter like this:

```
  reqCity: any;

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.reqCity = this._ActivatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('city');
    console.log('reqCity:' + this.reqCity);
  }
```

If I type the url like this:
http://localhost:4200/mycity

It redirects back to http://localhost:4200 and on the console I can see the following error message:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'mycity'

What am I doing wrong here?

When I try accessing like this:
http://localhost:4200?city=mycity
it seems to be working but doesnt capture the parameter
the console log says "reqCity:null"

I just want it like a SEO friendly approach like with "forward slashes" insted regular "?" marks.

http://localhost:4200/mycity
http://localhost:4200/somecity
http://localhost:4200/whatevercity
http://localhost:4200/etc

all should be resolved to the parameter "city".

Even when I write the paremter on the Template page its blank

```
<div>
    reqCity={{ reqCity }}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show also the template for the `AppComponent`. Is this the main component for the Angular application?

Comment: yes this is the main component, its not a complicated app with several components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `AppComponent` as a route component, as it is a bootstrap/root component, and also if you have a routing you need to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your `AppComponent` component. I can recommend you change a little bit your code, as this will be easier for you in the future.

First change your Routing to this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':city',
    component: CitySearchComponent,
  },
];
```

add `router-outlet` in `AppComponent` template:
app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and create `CitySearchComponent` component and do all of the imports in `app-routing.module.ts` and in `app.module.ts`

Comment: wow man.  you saved my headache!
you are absolutely correct I couldn't achieve this with AppComponent, so I have moved everything out to the CityComponent and now works like a charm.
AppComponent  doesnt have any codes other than <router-outlet></router-outlet> in the app.component.html. 
Thank you very much for your help! Kudos to you!